# Java 8 Lambda with Function<String, Object> as argument

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, functional-interface

Interesting compilation error in Lambda Java 8 (Oracle JDK)

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

I have a method call:

```
new CSVFile()
.of(new FileInputStream("MyFile.csv"))
.withColumnMapping("name", "fullName", s -> s.toUpperCase())
.withColumnMapping("gender", "gender", s -> s.toUpperCase());
```

This is the method I'm trying to call:

```
 public CSVFile withColumnMapping(final String columnName, final String   beanPropertyName, final Function<String, Object> columnTransformFunction) {
    columnMappings.add(new ColumnMapping(columnName, beanPropertyName, Optional.of(columnTransformFunction)));
    return this;
}
```

Compilation Error I get is:

```
[ERROR] /Users/sai/fun/reactivecsv/src/test/java/reactivecsv/CSVFileTest.java:[26,50] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method toUpperCase()
[ERROR] location: variable s of type java.lang.Object
```

Weirdly, This compiles

```
Function<String, Object> upperCaseConversion = String::toUpperCase;
new CSVFile()
.of(new FileInputStream("MyFile.csv"))
.withColumnMapping("name", "fullName", upperCaseConversion)
.withColumnMapping("gender", "gender", upperCaseConversion);
```

Why is the compiler not able to synthesise the lambda into a Function ?

Comment: By any change how your `CSVFile` class is declared? Is it generic?

Comment: That is correct: `public class CSVFile<T> `

Comment: Hence `new CSVFile()` is a raw type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you create `new CSVFile()` for generic type, it becomes a raw type. You must not use raw types. Creating it as raw type changes all its methods to raw as well, thus `withColumnMapping(String, String, Function<String, Object>)` becomes `withColumnMapping(String, String, Function)` and type of your lambda argument cannot be inferred. To fix your problem specify the proper generic arguments when calling the constructor.

Comment: That's indeed the issue.